# Divide each python dictionary value by total value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have
    `a = {'foo': 2, 'bar': 3, 'baz': 5 }`

Is there anyway I can get `a = {'foo': 0.2, 'bar': 0.3, 'baz': 0.5 }` in one line? Need to divide each value by total value... I just can't get it done.. :(

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sum the values, then use a dictionary comprehension to produce a new dictionary with the normalised values:

```
total = sum(a.itervalues(), 0.0)
a = {k: v / total for k, v in a.iteritems()}
```

You can squeeze that into a one-liner, but it won't be as readable:

```
a = {k: v / total for total in (sum(a.itervalues(), 0.0),) for k, v in a.iteritems()}
```

I gave `sum()` with a floating point starting value to prevent the `/` operator from using floor division in Python 2, which would happen if `total` and `v` would both be integers.

In Python 3, drop the `iter*` prefixes:

```
a = {k: v / total for total in (sum(a.values()),) for k, v in a.items()}
```

Note that you do *not* want to use `{k: v / sum(a.values()) for k, v in a.items()}` here; the value expression is executed for each iteration in the comprehension loop, recalculating the `sum()` again and again. The `sum()` loops over all N items in the dictionary, so you end up with a quadratic O(N^2) solution rather than a O(N) solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you don't need `total` here `{k:v/sum(a.values(), 0.0) for k,v in a.items()}`

Comment: @user3100115: in which case the `sum()` would run for *each and every key-value pair*, running a full loop over all values each time. You'd produce an N*N loop rather than an N loop. I'd pick linear over quadratic any time.

Answer (score 2):

I did it using a function

```
a = {'foo': 2, 'bar': 3, 'baz': 5}  
def func1(my_diction):  
    total = 0  
    for i in my_diction:  
        total = total + my_diction[i]  
    for j in my_diction:  
        my_diction[j] = (float)(my_diction[j])/total  
    return my_diction     

print (func1(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def div_d(my_dict):

    sum_p = sum(my_dict.values())

    for i in my_dict:
        my_dict[i] = float(my_dict[i]/sum_p)

    return my_dict
```

p.s i am totally new to programming but this is the best i could think off.