# How to return associated keys and values of a multidimensional dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this following dictionary

```
myDict={('A','X'): 1.0,
        ('B','Y'): 0.4,
        ('B','Z'): 0.6,
        ('C','X'): 0.1,
        ('C','Y'): 0.3,        
        ('C','Z'): 0.6,
 }
```

I need lists associated with the first key. For instance:

1) If I provide the first key 'A' I would like to get list1=['X'] and list2=[1.0]

2) If I provide the first key 'B' I would like to get list1=['Y','Z'] and list2=[0.4,0.6]

3) If I provide the first key 'C' I would like to get list1=['X','Y','Z'] and list2=[0.1,0.3,0.6]

I need only one of the three cases provided above depending on the first key I provide.

Edit: My dictionary is coming from the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616047/python-divide-items-of-a-dictionary-by-a-value-that-depends-on-the-first-key)

Is it possible to do that in a simple way? Maybe using list comprehension, but I was not able to do that...

Comment: Why don't you store the data in that format to begin with, then?

Comment: Not sure what your desired output is. A dict like `{'A': {'list1': ['X'], 'list2': [1.0]}, 'B': {'list1': ...}, ...}` maybe?

Comment: @Aran-Fey depending on the first key, the desire output is always one list1 and one list2.

Comment: AFAIK there is no good way to do this with dict, they are all O(n).  Use a different data structure (or re-key).

Comment: @DanielRoseman please see the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault` to initialize the two lists while you iterate over the dict items and appending values to the sub-lists.

```
o = {}
for (a, b), v in myDict.items():
    o.setdefault(a, [[], []])[0].append(b)
    o[a][1].append(v)
print(o)
```

This outputs:

```
{'A': [['X'], [1.0]], 'B': [['Y', 'Z'], [0.4, 0.6]], 'C': [['X', 'Y', 'Z'], [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to change the dictionary structure-

```
list2 = [val for ((key1, key2), val) in myDict.items() if key1=='A']
list1 = [key2 for ((key1, key2), val) in myDict.items() if key1=='A']
```

That should work. It's not the most efficient way to store the data for this use though.

Where the 'A' is you can put a variable with the desired key.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested dictionaries.

```
myDict={'A': {'X':1.0, 'Y':0.4}} ...}
```

You could get your lists like such.

```
list(myDict['A'].keys()) #list1
list(myDict['A'].values()) #list2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to restructure your dictionary in O(n) fashion:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for (k1, k2), v in myDict.items():
    d[k1]['labels'].append(k2)
    d[k1]['nums'].append(v)
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict({'A': defaultdict(list, {'labels': ['X'], 'nums': [1.0]}),
             'B': defaultdict(list, {'labels': ['Y', 'Z'], 'nums': [0.4, 0.6]}),
             'C': defaultdict(list, {'labels': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                                     'nums': [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]})})
```

Then each call for data will have O(1) complexity; for example:

```
print(d['C']['nums'])

[0.1, 0.3, 0.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pprint

key = 'A'

myDict = {('A', 'X'): 1.0,
          ('B', 'Y'): 0.4,
          ('B', 'Z'): 0.6,
          ('C', 'X'): 0.1,
          ('C', 'Y'): 0.3,
          ('C', 'Z'): 0.6,
          }

pprint.pprint(myDict.keys())
keys = myDict.keys()
list1 = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == key, keys))
list2 = []
for item in list1:
    tmp = list(filter(lambda x: x == item, myDict))
    list2.append(tmp)

pprint.pprint(list1)
pprint.pprint(list2)
```